# AutoIt update $input with MsgBox line for copy/paste

Tags: variables, input, updates, autoit

I have been making alot of random scripts lately, none of which are really useful for anything but they help me to understand various things and I use them for reference quite often... anyways, one of the outline button options for one of my scripts is a popup msgbox generator that generates a code that I can just copy and paste (there are alot of message boxes in the script)
but I am having trouble with the variable being displayed in the input '$codebox':

```
$code = "MsgBox(0, $title, $message)"  
GUICtrlSetData($codebox, $code)
```

this displays:

```
"MsgBox(0, $title, $message)"
```

rather than the data stored inside the variable. Yet, when I remove the quotation marks from the $code line, that actually brings the msgbox up(which I don't want) and returns a 1 to the codebox, rather than the MsgBox command..

Can I contain a variable inside a variable like this? I am not really sure how else to so this.. Does anybody have a possible workaround I could take a look at? I have searched around but I came up empty.

ps: the updated script can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/mKLTQh6n)

Comment: You can just use [`Eval(string)`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Eval.htm) to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, replace this line:

```
$code = "MsgBox(0, $title, $message)"
```

with this one:

```
$code = 'MsgBox(0, ' & '"' & $title & '"' & ', ' & '"' & $message & '"' & ')'
```

Answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/654966/autoit-update-input-with-msgbox-line-for-copy-paste) by Darius. (Thanks again)